# Checking 2 unique codes against the table and then registering the form

Tags: mysql, forms, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-validation

I've 2 different tables with 2 columns [code,status] each and the column 'code' contains unique code in integers (392,21,2981,2743,..etc) and they are about 100 in each table while the status tells if these codes were used or not.

I want the form to be only submitted when both of the provided codes from the user match the codes in those 2 tables and have the status '0'

I could create a very simple validation in the controller but that dosen't make much sense to what i just explained

```
public function formValidationPost(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request,[
                'name' => 'required|min:5|max:35',
                'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
                'mobile' => 'required|numeric',
                'code_a' => 'bail|required|exists:code_a,code',
                'code_b' => 'bail|required|exists:code_b,code'
            ],[
                'name.required' => ' The name field is required.',
                'name.min' => ' The name must be at least 5 characters.',
                'name.max' => ' The name may not be greater than 35 characters.',
            ]);

        dd('You  successfully added all fields.');
    }
```

So with my validation rules I want to be able to make sure that:

- Form doesn't submit unless both the provided codes are matched in the database ( code_a[table] and code_b[table] ) and their status to be '0'

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: What in, essence, is the issue? Your example seems to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: It works but i couldn't use the where clause to check the status to be 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-exists)

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

$this->validate($request,
[...
    'mobile' => 'required|numeric',
    'code_a' => [
        'bail',
        'required',
        Rule::exists('code_a', 'code')->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        })
    ],
    'code_b' => [
        'bail',
        'required',
        Rule::exists('code_b', 'code')->where(function($query) {
            $query->where('status', 0);
        })
    ]
],
[...]);
```

Comment: Class 'Illuminate\Validation\Rule' not found, I have searched on google but couldn't find any help